# How to sum specific values inside Pivot table in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, pivot-table

I have pivot table and it contains "Type" in Row field. There are different type available. Like AW,ED,MO,GT,SP. I would like to sum "AW" alone in one Row and all other types in second row to get the Amount value. I tried using formula in Calculated field. But it is not working.

```
Field1=IF(Type <>"AW";"Others";"AW")
```

Is this possible to get inside a pivot table? Help me

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Move **Type** to be to left-most field, then select everything *except* "AW".

Right click on the selected rows and Group them.  This will create **Type2**

Move **Code** to between **Type2** and **Type**

Within **Type2** you can now rename "Group1" to whatever you want, and Collapse "AW" to show the subtotal.

Or, I guess, just use a `SUMIF`?

**{EDIT}** *Example of Grouped PivotTable*
[image: Image of Data and PivotTable]

Comment: @Deepak Are there other items on the PivotTable interfering?  See screenshot in the answer for a demonstration